# Proper use of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I have a code like this:

In a Button Click I wrote this Code:

```
new Loadiing().execute();
```

It takes to the AsyncTask class That I created, My class Looks Like:

```
public class Loadiing extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        ProgressDialog d= new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", "Loading");


        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            **A method which returns some data in a arrayadapter and sets it;**
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            d.dismiss();

        }


    }
```

but it is just starting an alert dialog, nothing is done in the background and also the dialog is not being dismissed, what to do?

Comment: Call d.show() instead  ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", "Loading");

Comment: the whole point of using an asynctask is that you do your stuff in the background, and you apply it to the UI in the onPostExecute method. setting a listadapter requires being on the UI Thread. There must be a stacktrace in your logcat somewhere

Answer (score 2):

This should be,

```
d.show();
```

instead of, `ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", "Loading");`

**Update:** In your case,

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       d.setTitle("Loading");
       d.show();
     }
```

Comment: Your Idea works fine, but nothing is happenning in the background